# SQlite monthly averages

Tags: sqlite

I have 5 years of wind data with values recorded every 10 minutes. I have to get the average, min and max of some columns of every month, what I´ve done is

```
SELECT avg(S10_AVG), MIN(S10_AVG), max(S10_AVG)
FROM CP
WHERE strftime('%Y', FECHA)='2008' and strftime('%m', FECHA)='01'
```

Is it possible to make this for every month and year without doing 60 different queries? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_group_by.htm):

```
SELECT  strftime('%Y', FECHA), strftime('%m', FECHA), avg(S10_AVG), MIN(S10_AVG), max(S10_AVG)
FROM @WindData
GROUP BY strftime('%Y', FECHA), strftime('%m', FECHA)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    STRFTIME('%Y', fecha) AS year, 
    STRFTIME('%m', fecha) AS month, 
    AVG(s10_avg) AS avg, 
    MIN(s10_avg) AS min, 
    MAX(s10_avg) AS max
FROM cp
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y', fecha), STRFTIME('%m', fecha)
```

Comment: Works perfect and responded in less than a minute, but now I´m having another problem the result of this code is                2008 01 7.84206989247312 2.0 9,99
2008 02 6.74568965517241 1.0 9,99
2008 03 5.49014336917563 1.0                                                                                             The average is perfect but the max and min are wrong. I think the problem is using comma for decimal value

Comment: Try the above code but use `CAST(REPLACE(s10_avg,',','.') AS NUMERIC)` in place of each of the three occurrences of `s10_avg`.